# Use different base root than './' in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

is it possible to configure the base directory of a sails app? At the moment everything is in the root './', but I want to use something like './server/'. So that every files and folders for sails are in that directory, e.g. config, views, controllers, api etc.

How is that possible? Didn't found a solution...

Best regards,
Kersten

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `appPath` configuration option to set the path your app resides in.

There are a few different ways you could do this. One would be to pass in the `appPath` while lifting sails

```
sails lift --appPath=<path>
```

Another is to set the `appPath` in your `.sailsrc` file

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "hooks": {},
  "appPath": "<path>"
}
```

Comment: But not completely. The server starts, but something is still missing. "Trying to use unknown adapter, "sails-disk", in model Role". Also an index.html in assets is not recognized...

Comment: Sails looks for a bunch of things inside `appPath/node_modules`, so it might have something to do with that. The configuration I gave works for a barebones setup  of sails. For anything remotely complex you'll have to dig into the sails code and see how it loads that particular module/hook

Comment: At least normalize-datastore.js uses a reference to:
var node_modules = path.resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'node_modules');
So appPath is not an appropriate way to specify the base path. But thanks for your help...